# Bootstrap .table-responsive not working in panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Recent Transactions</div>
                    <table class="table table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                        <th>...</th>
                        <!-- th*5 -->
                        <th>...</th>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($audits as $audit)
                            <tr>
                                <td>...</td>
                                <!-- td*5 -->
                                <td>...</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works great on desktop but fails miserably on mobile screen. Only 2 columns show inside the panel and the rest just overflow...

How do I get BS to show scrollbars insted of just overflowing content

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.table-responsive` class doesn't go on the table itself it should go on a parent container. In this case the panel body `<div>`.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf1vLLt8/)

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  Recent Transactions
</div>
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>...</th>
      <!-- th*5 -->
      <th>...</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      @foreach($audits as $audit)
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <!-- td*5 -->
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```